# How to find specific key value?

Tags: python

```
{
 'Key1':{ 'price': 40,
        'amount': 30
       },
 'Key2':{ 'price': 50,
        'amount': 40
       },
 'Key3':{ 'price': 70,
        'amount': 50
       }
}
```

How to get all the prices?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way to do it:

```
d={
 'Key1':{ 'price': 40,
        'amount': 30
       },
 'Key2':{ 'price': 50,
        'amount': 40
       },
 'Key3':{ 'price': 70,
        'amount': 50
       }
}

prices=[k['price'] for i,k in d.items()]

print(prices)
```

Output:

```
[40, 50, 70]
```

Comment: You could also use `values()` here

Comment: And more meaningful names. `k` is usually for keys, but here it's values which are dicts. `v` or `d` would be more appropriate

Answer (score -1):

If the dictionary is called `dict1`, use:

```
[k['price'] for k in dict1.values()]
```

Comment: ````[k['price'] for k in dict1.values()]````

Comment: Apologies. It's late and I made an error.